# Enable data roaming only for specified providers?

Tags: htc-desire, data-monitoring, roaming

I'm living in a country A. My mobile phone provider is located in country B. Unfortunately, I have to enable data roaming to work both in country A and country B. This doesn't costs my roaming costs, because the providers in country A and B work together.

Unfortunately, I'm living also very close to country C. And a lot of time (during shopping, working etc) I go to country C. I always have to explicitly disable data roaming then. Sometimes I forget to do so and then I causes a lot of roaming costs.

So is it possible to allow data roaming only for specific providers? From the Android OS I don't think so, but it should be possible to do it progamatically? Every time the provider changes I would check if it it in the allowed list and if not I would disable data roaming?

Edit: Does anybody know if there are already apps which can do that? Otherwise I would start the development of suach an app.

Comment: At the moment we have the same problem in the UK with the Orange/T-mobile merge...

Comment: Ok, so do you haven't found a solution yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you used tasker/locale with this [plugin](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locale-carrierid-plug-in/com.schmeisserweb.carrierstring)?  You could then turn off data using [APNdroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/apndroid/com.codecarpet.apndroid.pro).